# Как проверить два списка адресов с геокоординатами на предмет пересечения друг с другом в радиусе 1000 метров?

Tags: java, массивы, динамические-массивы, gps, java-hashmap

Работаю в развитии крупной сети супермаркетов. Время от времени агенты по недвижимости предоставляют большой пул (список с адресами xls) объектов под аренду . Возникает необходимости проверить поступающие адреса на предмет пересечения с адресами действующей сети, т.к. минимальное расстояние между супермаркетами должно составлять более 1 км.

Я новичок в программировании, но имею большое желание автоматизировать данную задачу.
На тему чтения данных из xls с помощью Apache POI в интернете достаточно гайдов - с этим разберусь сам попозже.

Сейчас нуждаюсь в советах относительно следующего:

Нужно каждый адрес действующей сети сравнить с каждым адресом предложенного агентом списка объектов. Затем отсортировать по условия if(distance<1000)- отказ. Итоговым результатом по окончанию работы мы должны получить список адресов агента, которые находятся в удаленности более чем на 1000 метров от действующей сети.

Что я имею сейчас:

public class GPSHelper {

```
// ПИ

public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979324;

// Экваториальный радиус (м)
private static final  double EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137;


/**
 * Преобразовано в радианы (рад)
 * */
private static double rad(double d) {
    return d * Math.PI / 180.0;
}
/**
 
 * Есть формула на основе алгоритма в googleMap для получения расстояния между двумя широтой и долготой,
 * @param lon1 Долгота первой точки
 * @param lat1 Широта первой точки
 * @param lon2 Долгота второй точки
 * @param lat2 Широта второй точки
 * @return s возвращает расстояние в КМ 
 * */

 /*   public static double GetDistance(double lon1,double lat1,double lon2, double lat2) {
    double radLat1 = rad(lat1);
    double radLat2 = rad(lat2);
    double a = radLat1 - radLat2;
    double b = rad(lon1) - rad(lon2);
    double s = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin(a/2),2)+Math.cos(radLat1)*Math.cos(radLat2)*Math.pow(Math.sin(b/2),2)));
    s = s * EARTH_RADIUS;
    //s = Math.round(s * 10000) / 10000;
    return s;
} */

 //Я её немного изменил, для того чтобы вычислить расстояние между массивом координат действующей
 // сети и координатами адреса из предложенных агентом объектов. Результат возвращаем в ArrayList.

public static ArrayList<Double> GetDistanceBetweenArraysGPS (double[] lon1, double[]lat1, double lon2, double lat2) {
    ArrayList<Double> arrDistance = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < lon1.length; i++) {
        double radLat1 = rad(lat1[i]);
        double radLat2 = rad(lat2);
        double a = radLat1 - radLat2;
        double b = rad(lon1[i]) - rad(lon2);
        double s = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin(a/2),2)+Math.cos(radLat1)*Math.cos(radLat2)*Math.pow(Math.sin(b/2),2)));
        s = s * EARTH_RADIUS;
        //s = Math.round(s * 10000) / 10000;
        arrDistance.add(s);
    }
    return (arrDistance);
}
```

}

```
   //Ниже реализация метода в main
```

public class Task1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
   //Ниже случайные координаты

    double[] arrayLongitude1 = {37.652966, 37.729467, 37.733491, 37.645485 };
    double[] arrayLatitude1 = {55.587845, 55.585825, 55.911123, 55.583778};
    double arrayLongitude2 = 37.640291;
    double arrayLatitude2 = 55.586807;


    List dist = GetDistanceBetweenArraysGPS(arrayLongitude1, arrayLatitude1, arrayLongitude2, arrayLatitude2);

    for (int i = 0; i < dist.size(); i++) {
        if ((double) dist.get(i) < 1000){
            double a = (double) dist.get(i);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
 //вывод в консоль: 
 //805.7399867172365
 //469.5549013780302
    }

}
```

}

Таким образом, если в конце я получаю хоть 1 результат после условия if((double) dist.get(i) < 1000) , то это значит точка из координат 2 (предложенное агентом) - не подходит, поскольку есть пересечение с массивом координат из списка 1 адресов (действующая сеть), с расстоянием менее 1000 м.

Но это только 1 адрес, а точнее набор координат, я даже не знаю какой именно это адрес, поскольку нет никакого ключа. Я полагаю, что для сравнения двух наборов координат можно сделать вложенный цикл, где снаружи мы будем передавать массив координат 2 (предложенных агентом), а внутри будем передавать координаты 1 (собственной сети) и вычислять расстояние при помощи вышеуказанного метода. Что можно сделать дальше, чтобы на выходе получить список адресов, где условие (distance < 1000) выполняется и где не выполняется ? Как передать результаты в List или Map (адрес, значение)? Помогите решить, пожалуйста. Буду рад любым рекомендациям.

Comment: *Время от времени агенты по недвижимости предоставляют большой пул (список с адресами xls) объектов под аренду.* Большой - это сколько? десять тысяч? миллион? сто миллионов? *Нужно каждый адрес действующей сети сравнить с каждым адресом предложенного агентом списка объектов.* Ну и сравнивай... *я даже не знаю какой именно это адрес, поскольку нет никакого ключа.* Так и индекс массива сойдёт, если не перемещать элементы. *Затем отсортировать по условия if(distance<1000)- отказ.* Зачем? Если получил менее 1000 - в отказ, и считай следующий адрес. Если нет отказа по всем - пойдёт.

Comment: А для начала считай просто отклонение по одной координате. Если и по широте, и по долготе более 1000, то по прямой можно не считать, ибо заведомо больше.

Comment: @Akina _Большой - это сколько? десять тысяч? миллион? сто миллионов?_  более 15 тыс. своих и более 1 тыс. предлагаемых агентом. _Ну и сравнивай.._ моим способом мне нужно делать это более тысячи раз, для каждого предлагаемого адреса. _Зачем? Если получил менее 1000 - в отказ, и считай следующий адрес. Если нет отказа по всем - пойдёт_ ответил выше

Comment: *более 15 тыс. своих и более 1 тыс. предлагаемых агентом.* 15 миллионов сравнений с подсчётом расстояния (а с учётом моего второго комментария - хорошо если их останется 2000) - это ниачём.

Comment: @Akina _А для начала считай просто отклонение по одной координате. Если и по широте, и по долготе более 1000, то по прямой можно не считать, ибо заведомо больше._ Это хорошая мысль. Я пробовал прежде сравнивать координаты до 2 знаков после запятой в excel (если совпадает - не подходит) но из-за того, что долгота ближе к полюсам становится короче - возникает погрешность и нерелеватный результат. Но как добавить в код как дополнительное условие для того, чтобы сократить количество вычислительных операций - хорошая идея.

Comment: @Akina _15 миллионов сравнений с подсчётом расстояния_ Так я поэтому и написал свой вопрос - я не знаю как это сделать) Мне нужно получить результат сравнения с привязкой к адресу (подходит/не подходит). Пока что я имею только: массив координат 1 при вычислении с координатами 2 - даёт лист с результатами вычислений для каждой пары координат - всё.

Answer (score 0):

```
цикл по таблице кандидатов
    пометить кандидата как подходящего
    цикл по таблице магазинов
        если разность по X больше 1000 и разность по Y больше 1000
            перейти к проверке следующего магазина
        если расстояние меньше 1000
            пометить кандидата как неподходящего
            перейти к следующему кандидату
вывести кандидатов, помеченных как подходящие
```

Comment: `если разность по X больше 1000 и разность по Y больше 1000` - вот тут можете поподробнее?

Comment: @Uzden_Chi Ок, ещё раз. Если разность по КАЖДОЙ из координат для двух точек более 1000, то может ли быть расстояние между этими точками менее 1000? очевидно, что нет. А такая проверка гораздо быстрее, чем сразу применить вычислительноёмкий расчёт расстояния. К тому же подавляющее большинство пар удовлетворяют этому упрощённому условию.

Comment: Спасибо. Ушёл решать.